# Python 2.7.9 - How to save a raw_input in a variable to use it later?

Tags: python, class, variables, input, user-input

This is a bit of code from my text based game:

```
location_now = ""

class what_do:

    def whaat(self):
        interactions = what_do()
        print "*What will you do? Type help_ to see all the actions*"
        what = raw_input("")
        if what == "help_":
            print ' '.join(help_)
            interactions.whaat()
        if what == "travel":
            print "These are all the cities you can travel to:"
            mapje.map()
            travel = raw_input("To which city do you want to travel?(Takes 10 seconds)")
            if travel == locations[0] or travel == locations[1] or travel == locations[2] or travel == locations[3] or travel == locations[4] or travel == locations[5] or travel == locations[6] or travel == locations[7] or travel == locations[8]:
                print "You are now travelling to %s" % travel
                time.sleep(10)
                print "You are now in %s!" % travel
                location_now = travel
            else:
                print "That is no location in Skyrim!"
                interactions.whaat()
```

I want the input from `travel = raw_input` etc. to be stored and saved in the variable `location_now` (That I created before and outside the class). I have to use that input later in my code.

This class will be repeated because it is a sort of 'What would you like to do next?', so if the input from the second time, `what = raw_input("")`, is asked, it must replace the earlier input stored in `location_now = ""`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are worried that whatever is stored in your `location_now` variable would be overwritten if you use `raw_input()` again.
Luckily, that doesn't happen and if you have stored the result of a `raw_input()` in a variable, it remains intact.

Are you facing any problems that made you arrive to the conclusion?

Comment: No problems anymore, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would move your `location_now` variable into the class "what_do" as a static variable. ([Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python))

Also as a helpful hint, this line

```
if travel == locations[0] or travel == locations[1] or travel == locations[2] or travel == locations[3] or travel == locations[4] or travel == locations[5] or travel == locations[6] or travel == locations[7] or travel == locations[8]:
```

can be reduced to

```
if travel in locations:
```

This will check if `travel` is in the list of locations. Just a little hint to simplify your code! Isn't Python beautiful?

Comment: Thanks, I am learning so much of you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

In your whaat() function when you are trying to assign a new value to location_now you are actually creating a new local variable called location_now. You are not assigning a new value to the global location_now.

You need to declare location_now as global before your assignment so that you will actually assign a new value to the global variable.

```
global location_now
location_now = travel
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I fixed it on a different way: making a list of location_now and append travel to it. But thanks for the help, next time I will know what to do :)